# CI - drilling to a single post/thread

Tags: php, codeigniter

Could someone please enlighten me as to what I'm doing incorrectly - I'm currently following a net tuts+ video, which goes through the process of listing an array of posts, and then having the ability to click on one post, to be shown the detail.

I'm adapting the above method for my own solution/web application, but I'm at a loss as to why my array is blank.

I'm using this line to create link/anchor to the next controller

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Search/site/<?php echo $site->siteID; ?>"><?php echo $site->site_title; ?>
```

I've highlighted the code where I believe I'm going a miss,

Thanks

**Controller**

```
        class Search extends CI_Controller {

    public function display($sort_by = 'site_title', $sort_order = 'asc', $offset = 0)
    {
    $limit = 20;
    $data['columns'] = array(
        'site_title' => 'Site Name',
        'site_uprn' => 'Unique Property Reference'
    );
    $this->load->model('search_model');
        $results = $this->search_model->search_sites($limit, $offset, $sort_by, $sort_order);

        $data['sites'] = $results['rows'];
        $data['num_results'] = $results['num_rows'];


        //pagination

        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config = array ();
        $config['base_url'] = site_url("Search/display/$sort_by/$sort_order");
        $config['total_rows'] = $data['num_results'];
        $config['per_page'] = $limit;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 5;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $data['sort_by'] = $sort_by;
        $data['sort_order'] = $sort_order;



        $this->load->view('search', $data);
    }

    **function site($siteID){
    $this->load->model('search_model');
        $data['site_detail']=$this->search_model->site_detail($siteID);

        //$this->load->view('site', $data); 
        }   
}**
```

**Model**

```
 <?php
class Search_model extends CI_Model {

    function search_sites($limit, $offset, $sort_by, $sort_order){

        $sort_order = ($sort_order == 'desc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
        $sort_columns = array('site_title', 'site_uprn');
        $sort_by = (in_array($sort_by, $sort_columns)) ? $sort_by : 'site_title';



     //site table
     $q = $this->db->select('siteID, site_title, site_uprn')
        ->from('sites')
        ->limit($limit, $offset)
        ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);

    $ret['rows'] = $q->get()->result();

     //count query

    $q = $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count', FALSE)
        ->from('sites');

    $tmp = $q->get()->result();

    $ret['num_rows'] = $tmp[0]->count;

    return $ret;
    }

    **//sites details
    function site_detail($siteID){

    $this->db->select()->from('sites')->where('siteID', $siteID);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->first_row('array');
    }
}**
```

**View**

```
   <div id="right">
         <h5>Site Details</h5>
         <ul>
         <li><?php $site_detail['siteID']?></li>
          <li><?php $site_detail['site_title']?></li>
         </div>
```

Comment: I've changed the view to this, I think I was missing the echo statement.

**view**

     <h5>Site Details</h5>
  <ul>
  <li><?php echo $site['siteID']?></li>
   <li><?php echo $site['site_title']?></li>
  </div>

**controller**

    function site($siteID){
     $this->load->model('search_model');
      $data['site']=$this->search_model->site_detail($siteID);
      
      $this->load->view('site', $data); 
      } 

**model**

    function site_detail($siteID){
 
 $this->db->select()->from('sites')->where(array('siteID' => $siteID));$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->first_row('array');}

Comment: Yeah,  maybe you meant to use the short syntax `<?=`